# Find the emptiest spaces in a 3D point set

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I have a set of 100 fixed points inside a 3D rectangular box. I would like to find the five emptiest spaces in this set. An empty space would mean a sphere that

- has its center in the box
- is as large as possible
- does not contain any of the fixed points from the given set.

I have a solution in mind.

1. iterate over every position inside the box and calculate the distance to the nearest fixed point
2. discard every position in the resulting array that is not a local maximum
3. pick out the top five positions that have the largest distance.

That seems inefficient and only as precise as my initial iteration. Is there a better approach to this? An ideal solution would be something I can use in matplotlib or similar.

Comment: Use the Voronoi algorithm on your points, this will give, for all point, the set of nearest points. Then find the shortest distance from each point to its neighbours, and take the biggest 5 from this list.

Comment: @N74 The distances between points and their neighbors? I don't think that's the right approach. You need the distance from a vertex to a center of one of its adjacent cells. That's the radius of the Delaunay sphere that is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the Delaunay partition (which is the dual of the Voronoi partition and it is kind of like getting the convex hull of a set of 4D points). Each cell is inscribed in a sphere, called a Delaunay sphere. The five biggest spheres are the ones you are looking for.

Equivalently, as suggested in the comment, generate the dual Voronoi partition, and for each vertex, calculate the distance from that vertex to the center of one of the cells who share the vertex (doesn't matter which one, they are all equidistant from that vertex). By the way the centers of the cells are the points of your set initial set. The distances you are caclulating are the radii of the Delaunay spheres.