# Create a point with emptiest spaces in n-dimensional space

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computational-geometry

Given an n-dimensional space with boundaries and $k$ fixed points in the space. I would like to create a new point that has emptiest spaces in this set. An empty space would mean a sphere that:

- has its center in the box
- is as large as possible
- does not contain or touch any of the fixed points from the given set
- bounded by the boundaries of the space

This is actually very similar to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246109/find-the-emptiest-spaces-in-a-3d-point-set). But the difference is I want to create a new point with emptiest spaces instead of finding the point with emptiest spaces.

I don't need an exact result. An approximation is good enough.